# Calling methods in sequential order in parallel processing

Tags: c#, async-await

```
public async Task MyMethod(int i) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("I just got executed a long processing method! " + i);
}
```

Calling the method multiple times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{
  await MyMethod(i);
}
```

Here `MyMethod` is getting called 2 times parallelly. Is there a way so that it will work sequential, like method 1 should first execute and then, method 2?

Comment: What do you mean by "Here myMethod is getting called 2 times parallelly"? How have you determined that?

Answer (score 2):

Your `MyMethod` is not an asynchronous method, because it does not contain an `await`. If you use Visual Studio, you should get a warning. Hence your methods are executed sequentially.

We can turn `MyMethod` into an asynchronous method:

```
public async Task MyMethod(int i) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("starting MyMethod");
  await Task.Delay(100);
  Console.WriteLine("I just got executed a long processing method! " + i);
}
```

Now, your methods are still executed sequentially, because the `await` keyword makes sure, that the following code is executed only when the Task returned by `MyMethod` is completed. If you want to execute your methods parallely, just remove the `await` keyword:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{
  MyMethod(i);
}
```

You will see a different output: With the await, it should look like

```
starting MyMethod
I just got executed a long processing method! 1
starting MyMethod
I just got executed a long processing method! 2
```

Without the await, it should look like:

```
starting MyMethod
starting MyMethod
I just got executed a long processing method! 1
I just got executed a long processing method! 2
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7ySx3b